# Finding element using tag android

Tags: android

I need to find a view element using its tag in my activity. I tried getting the root view and used that root view to find the required element using tag but it always return null.

Any help is appreciated !!

Comment: add some code please ?

Answer (score 0):

```
private static ArrayList<View> getViewsByTag(ViewGroup root, String tag){
ArrayList<View> views = new ArrayList<View>();
final int childCount = root.getChildCount();
for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
    final View child = root.getChildAt(i);
    if (child instanceof ViewGroup) {
        views.addAll(getViewsByTag((ViewGroup) child, tag));
    } 

    final Object tagObj = child.getTag();
    if (tagObj != null && tagObj.equals(tag)) {
        views.add(child);
    }

} return views;
```

}

This is not my code, I found it on "stackoverflow" when I had similar problem.